How does a wireless charger work if there is no transfer of electrons?
I have read this:

the definition of electrical current is the flow of charge.
Now, it is also possible to transfer energy (and therefore power) through either free space or a conductor by electromagnetic fields. This does not require any charge carriers to move from one to the other, and indeed moves much faster than the charge carriers.

Is electric current actually the flow of electrical charge?
Now if I connect the battery to a traditional (wired) charger, I connect it to the power outlet, the power network that provides electricity (defined as the flow of electrons or any charge carriers), that is, my depleted battery will receive a flow of electrons, and charge up. Though, the wireless charger should not be able to do that.
In other words, does the charged up battery have more electrons than the depleted one (since the traditional/wired charger transfers electrons from the network to the battery)?
Question:

How does a wireless charger work if there is no transfer of electrons?


Depending on design, there may also not be any transfer of electrons from the wired charger either.  Moreover, there are no electrons transferred from the power plant to your house's sockets, because there are AC transformers in between

charge<>electrons. "electricity (defined as the flow of electrons or any charge carriers)" No.

There is never a net transfer of electrons. It's not as if you replenish a depleted electron storage. It's not even as if you give fresh electrons to the device and get the spent ones for recycling ;-). You do need to push electrons to the "other side" of the battery, but these can as well be electrons within the battery.

Note that, if batteries did "store electrons", it would make it difficult to keep a tidy battery drawer.  A fresh alkaline AA might have around a 2Ah capacity which comes out to 7200 coulombs.  Two such negatively charged batteries set an inch apart would repel each other with around 700 exanewtons (700 billion billion newtons) of force.

@K.A.Buhr Yikes!  I knew they would repel each other violently but I didn't realize it was anything like that much.

The time-varying magnetic field created by the wireless charger induces an electromotive force in the wireless charging coil of the device. This electromotive force (after being rectified) drives electrons from the positive terminal of the battery to the negative terminal, reversing the chemical reaction and recharging the battery.
Due to charge conservation, electrons are neither created nor destroyed in a battery. The discharging of a battery involves a spontaneous redox reaction which decreases the Gibbs free energy of the system. Electrons are simply moving from a higher-energy state to a lower-energy state within the device. The difference in energy is used to power the device, much like how the (gravitational potential) energy of rivers is harvested through hydroelectricity. Recharging the battery simply uses an external force to move them back to the high potential. The net charge is always zero. Therefore, external electrons are not necessary.

Thank you so much! What do you mean by higher chemical potential? Can you please tell me is this electrons bound tp a nucleus at higher orbitals? Or higher kinetik energy electrons that are freely moving?

@ÁrpádSzendrei The battery is driven by a redox reaction. The reaction occurs because doing so reduces the overall Gibbs free energy of the system (comprising all the chemicals and their electrons). And that does involve electrons changing orbitals. When the battery discharges, it is a galvanic cell. When it is charged, it is an electrolytic cell, which is the reverse.

One thing I like about this answer is that it implicitly brings in a bit of a frame challenge: "no electrons left the device as it depleted the charge, and you were fine with that; so why should you need electrons to add the device to replenish that charge?" (And doing so also invites the reader to wonder why they didn't feel that the discharge case is odd, which gets them to dig deeper about what's happening even in that step, which is the chemical reaction you reference.)

@ÁrpádSzendrei: Informally(!), imagine rolling a ball up a hill. We say the ball has higher potential energy, because you can easily cause it to gain a significant amount of kinetic energy (by nudging it back onto the slope and letting it roll down again). In the case of the battery, we are pushing electrons up the metaphorical hill to recharge it, and letting them "roll down" (again metaphorically) to discharge. At no point do any electrons enter or leave the system as a whole, on net (i.e. when charging by a wired connection, we may exchange electrons, but the total amount remains fixed).

@Kevin but what is this "metaphorical  hill", in reality, is it a higher orbital, or how do these electrons (and atomic, and molecular or ionic systems) store this extra energy?

@ÁrpádSzendrei Yes, the electrons can be considered to be moving from higher-energy orbitals to lower-energy orbitals. A simple Cu-Zn galvanic cell produces emf because of the difference in electronegativity between them. The electrons want to move from the higher-energy Zn valence orbitals to the lower-energy Cu valence orbitals.


Does the charged up battery have more electrons than the depleted one ?

No. A charged battery has exactly the same amount of electrons as a depleted one. It is just that the electrons in the charged battery are at a higher potential. The charged battery can then send these high potential electrons around a circuit to do work by running motors, lighting LEDs etc. etc. When they have done this work, the electrons (now at a lower potential) return to the battery.
A traditional battery charger pushes high potential electrons in at one end of the battery and removes the same amount of low potential energy electrons from the other pole of the battery. A wireless charger does the same thing using electromagnetic waves to move the electrons.

Thank you so much! I think this is the right answer. Can you please tell me what do you mean by "high potential electrons and low potential electrons"? Are these electrons bound by a nucleus, just at a "high or low" orbital? Or is it their kinetic energy?

@ÁrpádSzendrei Not quite either. In general, electric potential is something that just is, because electrons are charged particles in a universe where an electromagnetic field exists. But in the case of a battery, it's about which atoms certain electrons are bound to. An electron goes around the circuit from an atom that holds its electrons "less tightly" to one that holds them "more tightly", while inside the battery an ion moves from one molecule to another, bringing an electron in the opposite direction, and reaching an overall lower energy state.

You can think a wireless charger is similar to a power transformer where the primary coil is in the charger and the secondary is inside your device, including the necessary rectifier.
Wireless charging works only on short distance, the closer the better, for efficiency.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
